# Creating conditional statement in QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, conditional, if-statement

In QGIS 2.8 I have a large data set and I would like to search one field for any values over a certain amount (in this case 20) and if the value is larger than 20, I would like to return a value of 1 in another field, otherwise return a value of 0.

How can I implement it?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out this express in Qgis but it doesn't have results. Case
WHEN "A" = '1' and "LENGHT" <= 1 then "C"= '4' ELSE ERROR
END

Answer (score 50, accepted):

## The easy way

The most simple way to do this is to create a new field with the expression

```sql
"cat" > 20
```

This expression will evaluate to a boolean True/False which will be represented as an integer 1 or 0.

## Virtual Fields

You can also create a virtual field, which will automatically return an updated value in case the values in `cat` change (e.g. you edit the layer). Remember that the values of virtual fields will not be saved in the dataset and are only visible inside this QGIS project.

## More than boolean

If you have more than a simple "greater than", you need to use

```sql
CASE 
  WHEN "cat" > 100 THEN 2
  WHEN "cat" > 10 THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END
```

Answer (score 15):

I just tested this  : 
You can use the condition several times:

```
WHEN    cat =   1   THEN    205
WHEN    cat =   2   THEN    215
WHEN    cat =   3   THEN    225
WHEN    cat =   4   THEN    235
...
```

....
[image]

Answer (score 10):

Something like this perhaps:

```
case 
when "FIELD" > 20 then 1
else 0 
end
```

[image: Field Calculator]