# Multiple conditions for new field return NULL value in QGIS when using field calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes

I have a field with building height in levels.
I want to create a new field that returns 'low-rise' if buildinglevels < 4. That returns 'mid-rise' if building level is 4-9 and that returns 'high-rise' if building level > 9. 
I can do this for one condition

```
If( "buildingle" > 9, 'high-rise' ,pass)
```

But when trying the others, they overwrite the previous to NULL.
How to solve this?

Comment: You could use the 'CASE' function, like this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149624/creating-conditional-statement-in-qgis-field-calculator

Answer (score 8):

I prefer the SQL like syntax for if/else statements

```
CASE 
  WHEN "buildingle" < 4 THEN 'low-rise'
  WHEN "buildingle" >= 4 AND "buildingle" <= 9 THEN 'mid-rise'
  ELSE 'high-rise'
END
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use nested `if` condition in Field Calculator.

```
if( "buildingle" > 9, 'high-rise', if( "buildingle" < 4, 'low-rise', 'mid-rise'))
```

RESULT:

- .., 2, 3  -> 'low-rise'
- 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 -> 'mid-rise'
- 10, 11, ... ->
  'high-rise'