# Conditional calculation using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, masking, conditional

I want to apply an algorithm to calculate the clorophyll-a concentration of a reservoir using Sentinel 2.

To do this I need to create a mask using Sentinel's 2 band 11(infrared) to separate the water pixels from pixels with larger reflectance values than the water.

This is the algorithm:

```
(If B11 <=0.05 then 109.17*((1/B4-1/B5)*B6+ 19.03 else 0)
```

but I can't use if and else in QGIS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating Conditional Statement in QGIS Field Calculator](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149624/creating-conditional-statement-in-qgis-field-calculator)

Comment: That is not a duplicate, it is Field Calculator not Raster calculator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it is a raster layer you should use the Raster Calculator. It is a bit different then the Field Calculator described by the other answer and comments.
The expression should be something like this one:

```
("raster@11" <=0.05) * (109.17*((1/"raster@4"-1/"raster@5")*"raster@6"+ 19.03) + ("raster@11" >0.05) * 0
```

where "raster" is the name of your sentinel raster layer and @11 or @5 is the band number. The principe is as follows:

```
(condition) * value_if_true + (Else condition) * ElseValue
```

See also https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_analysis.html#raster-calculator

Answer (score 4):

You can use CASE...WHEN in an expression:

```
CASE 
 WHEN B11 <=0.05 THEN (109.17*((1/B4-1/B5)*B6+ 19.03
 ELSE 0 
END
```